# Error passing Pandas Dataframe to Scikit Learn

Tags: python, pandas

I get the following error when passing a pandas `dataframe` to scikitlearn algorithms:

```
invalid literal for float(): 2.,3
```

How do I find the row or column with the problem in order to fix or eliminate it? Is there something like `df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]` for a specific value (in my case I guess `2.,3`)?

Comment: Do one of your columns have `2.,3` as a cell value? Try to_numeric() or print df.dtypes to see what type of data pandas is inferring. It probably says 'object'.

Comment: Yes correct, df.dtypes gives me object for one of the columns that should be  float64. How do I find out where is the problematic cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what column it is, you can use

```
df[df.your_column == 2.,3]
```

then you'll get all rows where the specified column has a value of `2.,3`

You might have to use

```
df[df.your_column == '2.,3']
```